# Keep image width same as height when height is set in percentage

Tags: html, css

I'm not too sure if this can be achieved in pure CSS, though it would be preferable. I have an image:

```
<img src="#" class="article-thumb">
```

CSS:

```
.article-thumb {
    height: 55%;
}
```

So, how can I make the `width` to equal whatever the `height` is? I'm trying to achieve an image that's a perfect circle (so I obviously have some `border-radius` applied), and that can also scale to fill as much as it's container (actually to fill `55%` of it's container in `height` to be specific)

Comment: Will the height be dynamically changed after page load? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Yes it will. E.g. the height will change when the device it's viewed on is in either portrait or landscape mode.

Comment: I'm not sure if this technique would work for you, but you could set the image as the background of a div and set `background-size` to `cover`: http://jsfiddle.net/4d3eqagy/ This negates the need for any dynamic sizing as the browser will then take care of it for you.

Comment: There's a weird thing in CSS. If you have a height in percent, it will depend on the width of the container. So, be careful with that.

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan. I typically find background images much easier to work with in these kinds of situations.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's great, but what if that image is now contained in another div, and the containing div can resize. How can the image/avatar-container resize to fill 55% of it's parent and still keep it's round shape?

Comment: It will always be round (no matter the height/width) due to `border-radius: 50%`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/4d3eqagy/

Comment: You'll notice that when the containing div is rectangular, the image takes on an oval shape rather than a circle.. This is my problem.

Comment: If image is square , width:auto should work ...no?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it which involves some extra mark-up so it may not appeal to everyone.

Let `.wrap` be some parent, containing block with some width and height (can be in % values).

Define an inline-block child container, `.framer`, whose width is a % of the parent, for example, 23%.

Within `.framer`, place a square image `.aspect-setter` (dimensions not critical, just keep it small) and set the width to 100%.  The image will then scale to the width of `.framer` and `.framer` will shrink-to-fit the image (because it is an inline-block) and keep its intrinsic shape (because height is auto).  Use `visibility: hidden` to hide the image while keeping it in the content flow.

Define `.avatar-container` as an absolutely positioned element and use the offsets to scale it to fit `.framer`.  Since `.framer` is square, `.avatar-container` will also be square.

Using an extra image is not overly elegant, but it gets the job done.

```css
.wrap {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.framer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    width: 23%;
}
.aspect-setter {
    vertical-align: top;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.avatar-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url('http://www.wisportsfan.com/siteresources/images/defaultavatar.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="framer">
        <img class="aspect-setter" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
        <div class="avatar-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```